# Autocorrect NSString on iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, nsstring, autocorrect

Basically what I want to do is to use Cocoa's autocorrection feature on NSString.

E.g. [string autocorrect] would return what it text field shows in a popup

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know you can't, besides, why would you want it?  If you want to auto correct a string then it would have to be inputted from somewhere, either by you or by the user.  If it's by you then just run spell check before you input it in your code.  If the user inputs it, just enable it in the text field using something like:

```
    textfield.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeYes;
```

Comment: There's a table, which user may filter. I was thinking about applying some smart filtering and filter by both user-entered and user-entered-corrected strings..

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old post, but now you can use `UITextChecker` to do this. There's a nice post about it on NSHipster: http://nshipster.com/uitextchecker/